# How to perform a GET request to a HTTPS endpoint using Android Studio

Tags: java, android, json, https, get

I am a relatively new android developer. I am trying to develop a simple app to teach myself how to consume an api. I found a simple code which displays JSON in a Toast view, by reaching out to a simple JSON at a mock url. I used a service called Mocky to generate a url I could query against and get the JSON string which is then displayed on my android device.

This test works brilliantly. However, the mock api uses HTTP, not HTTPS.

This is where I am stuck. I am trying to do the same thing except to an HTTPS endpoint. I've searched many answers on StackOverFlow, but none quite get me there.

I've seen posts using Volley, and other posts going as deep as certs. I am just trying to get the simplest possible way to query an HTTPS endpoint with a GET request which returns the JSON string containing the data. Also, I have seen many answers with authorizations such as username and password.

However, I have a key I need to use. I also need help with this, as in, how to use it.
I have tested my system using cURL, and that works, that is, I get the full JSON returned in my command line.

So, I know the data is there, I just can't get it!

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

By the way, the sample JSON looks like this (I've shortened things):

```
[
  {
    "LL1": 0,
    "LL2": 0,
    "cT": 19,
    "eT": 20,
    "tl": 0,
    "vs": 0
  }
]
```

Comment: Querying an HTTPS endpoint requires to authenticate as a first step. This what differs from HTTP and makes it more difficult to handle. You can't expect to just send a request and get your info as with HTTP. How to start an authentication session depends on the API, so you should specify here what it is in your case (it should be in the documentation)

Comment: Hi matthiasbe. Thanks for your reply. Yes, I do have an access key to use for authentication. The problem is I don't know how to use it. I've been experimenting and researching, but no success so far. I see stuff about usernames and passwords, but nothing for something like an authentication key.

Comment: Could you explain how your API works exactly, what you tried and why it doesn't work ? As is I think your question is to broad to answer.

Comment: Hi matthiasbe. Sorry I took some time to reply. Was working away. So, I am much clearer as to what I am trying to do. The api endpoint is: https://<app id>.data.<site>.org/api/v2/query/<device id>?last=20s and I need to pass the access key (which I have) somehow on the end of that address. I thought it might be like: https://<app id>.data.<site>.org/api/v2/query/<device id>?last=20s&key=<access key>. However, I am still not authorized. It's got to be something simple I am messing up; I just can't see it! Any idea with this new information?

Comment: I do have the curl working: curl \ --header "Content-Type: application/json" \ --header "Authorization: key <key>" --request GET \ https://<app id>.data.<site>.org/api/v2/query/<device id>?last=20s

Comment: Hi, don't hesitate to edit your question to add such precisions. You will be able to use code highlighting and it will be much clearer. You can edit as much as you want.

Comment: About your problem, I don't see the problem right now sorry. But it seems legitimate, and if you add this information to your post, along with an example full request which doesn't work and a link to the documentation, you may have answers

Comment: Hi. Sorry about that. Here's my second try. There are certain bits of information I don't want to share. API endpoint:  `https://<app id>.data.<site>.org/api/v2/query/<device id>?last=20s`  The URL with the key I think should be:  `https://<app id>.data.<site>.org/api/v2/query/<device id>?last=20s&key=<access key>`  The curl that I have working is:  `curl \ --header "Content-Type: application/json" \ --header "Authorization: key <key>" --request GET \ https://<app id>.data.<site>.org/api/v2/query/<device id>?last=20s`

Answer (score 0):

that should be simple as ordinary http request if the https end point use a valid ssl certificate not self signed certificate, the problem is whether you use https end point with self signed certificate or you got wrong end point

Comment: Hi Mister Ab. I am very noobie with respect to certificates and I did come across some information about that. So, I will have to learn a bit more.